# Tableau dashboard view in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, tableau-api, dmz, web-application-firewall

My client would like to use their internal Tableau Server (residing behind the DMZ) to serve up visualizations in a public-facing website.

We would like to present the Tableau generated views, dashboard, storyboard, etc. on SharePoint website without having to expose Tableau server to public internet. From what I can see, the only way to accomplish that is to make direct call to Tableau server via SharePoint webpart or iframe.

Is there any way to hide Tableau server behind the firewall and still able to fetch its interactive views on public website?

Right now we host Tableau in our internal server, residing behind DMZ firewall

Comment: To be clear, is your SharePoint 2013 environment hosted on premises or in the cloud? And in either case, is the SharePoint environment publically exposed through the Internet?

Comment: Our SharePoint 2013 environment is hosted on premises and it is exposed to the Internet.